# Simplify these boolean expressions?

Tags: c++, boolean-logic

I am not sure if I am simplifying these boolean expressions correctly:

```
1. (A && B) || B
2. (A || B) && A
3. !(A || B) && A
4. !(A && B) || !B
```

simplified expressions:

```
1. A && B
2. A || B
3. !B && A
4. !A || !B
```

Comment: 3 of the 4 are wrong.  You can make a truth table for each expression to check.

Comment: Well the best 2 ways to check are 1) Read documentation or 2) Right a program and check if it is the same or not...

Comment: You can use [Karnaugh Maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) to simplify these.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question

Answer (score 3):

Fairly easy to sort out with some truth tables

```
1. (A && B) || B

A B | E
0 0 | 0
0 1 | 1
1 0 | 0
1 1 | 1

Simplified: B
################
2. (A || B) && A

A B | E
0 0 | 0
0 1 | 0
1 0 | 1
1 1 | 1

Simplified: A

Algebraically:
Using our identity that we've derived from part 1:
(A || B) && A --> (A && A) || (A && B) --> A || (A && B) --> A
#################
3. !(A || B) && A

A B | E
0 0 | 0
0 1 | 0
1 0 | 0
1 1 | 0

Simplified: 0

Algebraically (via demorgans)
!(A||B)&&A --> (!A && !B)  && A --> !A && !B && A
--> (A && !A) && !B --> 0 && !B --> 0

##################
4. !(A && B) || !B
A B | E
0 0 | 1
0 1 | 1
1 0 | 1
1 1 | 0

Simplified: !A || !B
```

Most of these can be done algebraically as well, but the truth tables will really make your life easy.